# Unit Testing nested methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

While I understand that when unit testing a method it is very important to mock all it's dependencies, what I still have confusion about is what happens when the method is nested? Do I mock only the dependencies of the parent method or do I mock the dependencies of the child method(s) as well or do I set expectations on the calls to the dependent object and set the exact return values so that I can perform the test that I want?

For instance, in the below example, if we want to unit test the method B, do we only mock `IHttpClientFactory` & `ILogger` or do we  also set the method's return value to what we are actually expecting because otherwise when the test method executes it goes ahead and tries to execute methodC where it fails because the value of `client` after the line `var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient()` executes is null?

```
using System.Net.Http;
...

public class classA
{
   private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
   private sting url = "...";
   private ILogger _log { get; set; }
   ...

   public classA(ILogger log, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, ...)
   {
     _log = log;
     _clientFactory = clientFactory;
     ...
   }

   public string methodB(string inputB)
   {
      var varB = methodC(inputB);
      ...
      return ..;
   }

   public string methodC(string inputC)
   {
      ...
      var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(inputC, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
      responJsonText = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      ...
      return ..;
   }

}
```

Comment: It is called unit test because you test a single unit - the smallest public part you can find in your code: f.i. the method of a class. If this method calls another method (of course of the same class, otherwise it would be an dependency you have already mocked) then you should not care about, because you will write some unit tests for that other method too :o)

Comment: On the other hand if the methodB would call some protected or private methods (of the same class) would you care about - from the caller point of view? No, you would expect that the method will work as documented and you would not care about the implementation details. And that is exactly what you test with unit tests: Does the unit behave as documented

Comment: You only need to mock the methods you are actually calling, you don't need to stub out the whole class. And yes, you will mock the responses to be what you are expecting for the test case. Whatever the specific unit under test needs to complete the test, nothing else matters from the mocks.

Answer (score 1):

So you have an HTTP client, a high-level method that gets you some structured data and a low-level method that gets you the contents of the response.

These things are more of an art than hard-cut rules, but the rule I prefer most of the time is to write code that *can* have all of its I/O abstracted and then mock or test-implement the I/O itself. This way the most amount of business logic would be testable.

I/O can be many things - file, network, user input, but even things such as getting a certificate from the cert store or reading registry setting. Any data that originates at runtime from outside the process is I/O, no matter the method.

When you mock functionality, the most common things you're interested in is validating the method's input or emulating its output (or both). So in your mock, you shouldn't be too concerned with the actual implementation since you're not testing your mocked method - you're testing whatever is calling it.

So... about your sample code. If you're trying to test MethodB, you'd need MethodC to have a test implementation - either by mocking the HttpClient it relies on or by making it `virtual` and having it overridden in test.

Side note: reuse the HttpClient, keep it with the class

Comment: Here is an example how MS does that https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/master/src/Mobile/eShopOnContainers/eShopOnContainers.Core/Services/RequestProvider

Comment: @SirRufo good example! This is the way to abstract the high-level client. If the OP is writing that client, then the abstraction would be around the HttpClient